# CAN-Controller acceptance filtering with the SJA1000 (ESP32)

Tags: c, filter, mask, can-bus, esp32

I'm try to use the acceptance filter from the SJA1000 CAN-Controller on a ESP23. 
The Messages should be filtered in a defined area (e.g. Arbitration ID from: 0x30 to: 0x35).

Example for filtering a single message (0x30):

```
#define CAN_FILTER_CONFIG_ACCEPT()  {.acceptance_code = 0x1500000, .acceptance_mask = 0xffffff, .single_filter = true}
```

If I want to filter a defined area (0x30 - 0x35):

```
int calc_mask(int startID, int endID) {
    int size_of_range = endID - startID;
    unsigned int acceptance_mask = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    int i;

    for (i = startID; i <= endID; i++ {
    acceptance_mask = ~(acceptance_mask & i);
    }

    return acceptance_mask;     
}

acceptance_code = 0x30;
acceptance_mask = calc_mask(0x30, 0x35);
```

> 0x30 : 110000
>   NAND  0x31: 110001
>   NAND  0x32: 110010
>   NAND  0x33: 110011
>   NAND  0x34: 110100
>   NAND  0x35: 110101
>   0xF : 001111
>   acceptance_code = 0x6000000: 0000 0110 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
>   acceptance_mask = 0x1FFFFFF: 0000 0001 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111

filtered Messages:
    wanted:
    14:21:17.754 -> CAN Message: 30  110000
    14:21:17.754 -> CAN Message: 31  110001
    14:21:17.787 -> CAN Message: 32  110010
    14:21:17.787 -> CAN Message: 33  110011
    14:21:17.787 -> CAN Message: 34  110100
    14:21:17.821 -> CAN Message: 35  110101
    unwanted:
    14:21:17.821 -> CAN Message: 36  110110
    14:21:17.821 -> CAN Message: 37  110111
    14:21:17.855 -> CAN Message: 38  111000
    14:21:17.855 -> CAN Message: 39  111001
    14:21:17.855 -> CAN Message: 3A  111010
    14:21:17.889 -> CAN Message: 3B  111011
    14:21:17.889 -> CAN Message: 3C  111100
    14:21:17.889 -> CAN Message: 3D  111101
    14:21:17.923 -> CAN Message: 3E  111110
    14:21:17.923 -> CAN Message: 3F  111111

Documentation ESP32 CAN-Controller (Acceptance Filter):
https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-reference/peripherals/can.html#acceptance-filter

Documentation SJA1000 CAN-Controller (6.4.15 Acceptance filter):
https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/SJA1000.pdf

Does anyone have an idea how to get the not wanted Messages filtered?

Comment: You probably just want to do `acceptance_mask = 0x30 | 0x31 | ... | 0x35`. Then invert it all with `~` if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably cannot filter all unwanted messages. But you can narrow down a bit.
For a suitable mask you must treat the ones and the zeros separately.

```
uint32 mask_ones = mask_zeros = ~0;

for (int id = startId; id < endId; id++)
{
  mask_ones  &=  id;
  mask_zeros &= ~id;
}
uint32 mask = mask_ones | mask_zeroes;
uint32 value = startId & mask;
```

This creates a mask which includes all bits that are set to 1 in every allowed value and also all bits that are set to 0 in every allowed value.
This should get rid of all values above `0x37`.

Example:

```
ones = zeros = 11111111
CAN Message: 30 110000 => mask_ones = 00110000; mask_zeros = 11001111
CAN Message: 31 110001 => mask_ones = 00110000; mask_zeros = 11001110
CAN Message: 32 110010 => mask_ones = 00110000; mask_zeros = 11001100
CAN Message: 33 110011 => mask_ones = 00110000; mask_zeros = 11001100
CAN Message: 34 110100 => mask_ones = 00110000; mask_zeros = 11001000
CAN Message: 35 110101 => mask_ones = 00110000; mask_zeros = 11001000
unwanted:
CAN Message: 36 110110
CAN Message: 37 110111
CAN Message: 38 111000

mask =  00110000 | 11001000 = 11111000 = 0xF8
value =  00110000 & 11111000 = 00110000 = 0x30
```

Update:
The calculation above was broken. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that what you are trying to achieve is not possible if you are using a single filter. For example, you could define

```
   .acceptance_code = 0x30,
   .acceptance_mask = 0x03,
```

This would accept IDs in the range 0x30 to 0x33 - but exclude 0x34 and 0x35.

On the other hand, with `acceptance code = 0x34` and `acceptance mask = 0x01` you would be allowing 0x34 and 0x35 - but excluding 0x30 - 0x33.

I notice that the acceptance filter can be placed in a *dual* filter mode, however - with the proviso that it can not be used to filter an extended ID. Maybe this will allow you to define complementary filters as defined above.

Comment: Yes, the Problem is that i need to use also Extended ID's.  So i think the only Option is to implement an Software Filter.

Comment: @PhilippFu: Thanks for clarifying.